# Is there a convention for brunch.io style 'skeletons' - for Ember / CLI?

Tags: git, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm getting to a point with Ember CLI where I need to follow a long list of things at the beginning of every project. (I'm making many projects a week)

add stylus, add fastclick -- copy and paste in the content security policy into the environment ---- partial out the head ... drag over some styles from bower... - most of this is extremely easy and fast - it's not that I'm lazy - with the package.json - or bower.json I could just save them - and paste them into new projects and install/update --- but I imagine there to be a better way.

I am thinking about a branch of a base install... with a git ignore or something... but I'm just wondering if there is a convention and I'm just missing it... like, instead of 'skeleton' it's called 'hampster-wheel' or something.

Any help to keep the refactoring down would be greatly appreciated.  : )

Comment: You could certainly manage that with an addon that contained blueprints.

Comment: So, so far - one or more think this is a stupid question, and @steveax 's answer is 'no.'

Comment: @sheriffderek interested in your current workflow for this?  Looking for something similar myself and wondering if blueprints is the right option?

Comment: @rossjha I've haven't had the time to invest in exploring this further. I guess it's been a year! It would be so cool if I could `ember new project-name derek-style` and have all of my defaults get added be ready to go. I'll report back if I ever find the path. Please do the same. : )

Comment: @sheriffderek Thanks for getting back to me!  Yep would be nice.  Will let you know if I come across anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer is... that there *might be,* but as of this date - no one on stack overflow knows of anything like it.

Comment: Still not sure why you don't want to go the addon route. Works quite well for us with multiple application (base styles, test helpers, templates, components, etc.) and I think that is the "ember way" to do things like this. If you have a better proposal, you can [create an RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs)

Comment: I'm thankful for the suggestion, and I might go that route - but the question was really more about if there is a standardized way that people were packaging things like this. - and what I gather is simply "no / not yet."